# WF state machine workflow service and exceptions in triggers

Tags: iis, exception, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice, sqlworkflowpersistencese

I have a state machine working as a *workflow service*, having receive/send-reply activities as  triggers for transitions.

Before send replies back, I have to do some work.
Problems come when exceptions happen in the process before sending the reply. In such case, if I don't handle the exception, the whole workflow is suspended; anyway, I shouldn't move to the next state if the requests wasn't properly handled.

Would it be enough to wrap the whole state machine with a **Try/catch**? Will the state machine recover from the last persisted state (I'm using Sql persistence)?
Are there other solutions?

Remark: workflows are hosted in IIS.

Thanks